# Disable Button in main window

Tags: javascript

I'm making an application and is for linking their email and I want that when the user goes to the "file" (there will be shown buttons to link/submit emails by opening new tab and after they submit the email the opened tab will be closed) after the "new" tab being closed a continue button to be shown so user can continue to the next part

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can better assist.

Comment: What do you mean by "linking their email"?

Comment: Try something like: `<button type="button" onclick="opener.document.getElementById('continue').style.display='block'; window.close()">Save and continue</button>`

Comment: hey mplungjan https://prnt.sc/oxnzd3 this is my project and i want when i go to this file /link.html that continue button to doesnt be showed but when i click like on gmail write my email and click save the new window that opened from clicking on gmail icon to be closed and the continue button to be showed

Comment: So you need to somehow say they added it. either postMessage or localstorage/cookies with polling.....

Comment: One important thing on this site are tags (the formatted words below the question). The question you linked to has the tags `wpf` and `vb.net`, which are different technologies than `javascript`, which is why the answers to that question won't help you. If you are searching on Stack Overflow, you can add tags to your search criteria using brackets, like `[javascript] disable button in parent window`, which might help you find similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did in my website and its working. You tell the 2nd window to activate a function from the first one when the user clicked a button.

Here is how I did it:

Window 1:

```js
function enableButton() {
  document.getElementById('disabled').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('disabled').innerText = 'not disabled';
}
```

```html
<a>click me</a>
<br>
<button id='disabled' disabled>im disabled</button>
```

Window 2:

```js
function enableHim() {
  let oldWin = window.opener;
  oldWin.enableButton();
}
```

```html
<button id='b' onclick='enableHim()'>click here to enable other button</button>
```

Comment: hello this works but can u modify this code and make it not disable but i want to make it display:none when  the other button clicks to make the main button display:block